# Spring Boot Cache not evicted through custom evict method

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

After defining a Spring Boot cache like so:

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = ["test"])
class TestCache {
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = ["test"], key = "#testId")
    fun find(testId: String): String { ... }

    @CachePut(cacheNames = ["test"], key = "#testId")
    fun put(testId: String, set: String): String { ... }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = ["test"], key = "#testId")
    fun evictByTestId(testId: String) { }

    fun evictByFooId(fooId: String): Boolean {
        /* some processing to convert fooId to testId */
        val testId = fooId
        evictByTestId(testId)
        return true
    }

}
```

when I try to evict an entry, it perfectly works using the method with the CacheEvict annotation:

e.g. `cache.evictByTestId("test123")`

but **does not** delete the cache entry (also no exception) when using the defined helper method, which processes some data and then calls the annotated eviction method:

e.g. `cache.evictByFooId("test123")`

I stepped through the code with the debugger, both testIds are definitely the same.

Is there some annotation missing on the evictByFooId method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring annotations do not work when a method invokes another method in the same class. Spring uses AOP to implement many of their annotations and only external invocations cause annotation processing to occur. In your case your `evictByFooId()` method is calling `evictByTestId()`, a method in the same class with the `@CacheEvict` annotation. You will have to duplicate the `@CacheEvict` annotation on `evictByFooId()`.